# How to redirect blog to another url using htaccess

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess

I have recently moved my blog from `https://mobileframers.com/blog` to `https://blog.domain.com` the issue is that google is looking for bog pages which does not exists, I want to redirect individual blogs like following using htaccess:

`Redirect https://mobileframers.com/blog https://blog.mobileframers.com`

`Redirect https://mobileframers.com/blog/test-1 https://blog.mobileframers.com/test-1`

`Redirect https://mobileframers.com/blog/test-2 https://blog.mobileframers.com/test-2`

Comment: For starters: The `Redirect` directive does not match on full URLs. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect: _"The old URL-path is a case-sensitive (%-decoded) path beginning with a slash. A relative path is not allowed."_

Answer (score 0):

To redirect all requests from old domain **with** subdirectory to new domain **without** subdirectory while maintaining the remainder of path and the full query string, use mod_rewrite inside your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://blog.mobileframers.com/%1 [R=301,NC]
```